# How do I tell WPF to treat my control's Padding as part of the control?

Tags: wpf-controls

If I add some padding between the border of a control and the content, clicking/mousing over the padding doesn't work.  When I mouseover the border, my trigger is activated.  Then I reach the padding, and the mouseover deactivates.  Then I reach the content and it reactivates.

How can I make it so the padding is considered part of the control?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just use a transparent inner border instead of padding.